# unable to display chinese characters in error_log

Tags: utf-8, stdout, php-7.2

I have a php script that pump chinese characters into stdout via error_log. It goes like this:

`error_log(">>>>>>>>>>article imported: ". $node->title ."(".$node->nid.")");`

but this is what I get

`>>>>>>>>>>article imported: \xe5\x88\xa9\xe7\x89\xa9\xe6\xb5\xa6\xe5\x86\x8d\xe5\x90\x9e\xe5\xa4\xaa\xe5\xa6\x83\xe7\xb3\x96(934909)`

Honestly I am not sure what I could have done as I have already set the headers as `header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset: UTF-8");` at the top of the file. Tried wrapping both $node->title in `utf8_encode` or `utf8_decode` also does not work. What else can I do to ensure chinese log message pipe to stdout the correct way?

Comment: Is the log logging literally "backslash eks eeh five …", or is that merely what whatever tool you're using to read the log file is displaying…? Use a hex editor to look at the raw bytes in the log file.

Comment: it is piped out to stdout and wasn't save to any log file so I am not sure what hex editor I can use

Comment: Then perhaps your terminal simply isn't interpreting it correctly.

Comment: and I just tried adding `error_log("Test Chinese Characters: 廖刚征");`, shows up as `Test Chinese Characters: \xe5\xbb\x96\xe5\x88\x9a\xe5\xbe\x81` in the docker logs console

Comment: So the console doesn't handle UTF-8 output properly. You'll need to tell us more about what console you're using how/where/why.

Comment: the console I use is ZSH. I was using docker logs to output the log messages. So I wasn't sure is the problem comes from docker or zsh. also I have already place `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` so I wasn't sure what else I can do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191948/discussion-between-moses-liao-gz-and-deceze).